# ATLComTime.h is part of what redistributable?

Tags: c++, com, dll, atlcom

I added functionality to a code base someone else wrote and while the "Not using ATL" flag was set in VS2005 I see that there is `#include <ATLComTime.h>` in one of the files.  I have only sent the C-Runtime library ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah%28VS.80%29.aspx)) redistributable.  The client can not get the code to worktheir machines.  They receive a "DLL entry point not found" error.  I feel that it's some sort of missing DLL or library on the target machine since we've been able to install it in all of our test machines.

They want me to make sure that I don't send a "bogus" redistributable to a client.  Since I can't seem to find ultimately which redistributable this header pertains I'm asking here.  I'm at a loss.  Can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure the project to link statically with ATL (Project | Properties -> Config Properties -> General -> Use of ATL) executable, or distribute atl.dll with your application.